# reduce calculation precision to speed up execution

Tags: python, csv, decimal

I have a data acquisition system which takes measurements for a few minutes and generates a csv file with 10 million rows and 10 columns. Then I import this csv file in Python (csv.reader), perform a bunch of operations on the acquired numeric data (but ‘only’ 10000 rows at a time, otherwise the computer memory would be overwhelmed). In the end, I export the results in another much smaller csv file (csv.writer).
The problem is that the runtime is very long and I want to speed it up. When I open the original csv file with Notepad I see that the numbers have up to 16 digits each, like 0.0015800159870059, 12.0257771094508 etc. I know that the accuracy of the DAQ is 0.1% at best and most of the trailing digits are noise. Is there an elegant way of forcing Python to operate **globally** with only 7-8 digits from start to finish, to speed up the calculations? I know about error propagation and I’m going to try different settings for the number of digits to see what the optimum is.
Please note that it is not enough for me to build a temporary csv file with ‘truncated’ data (e.g. containing 0.0015800, 12.0257771 etc) and simply import that into Python. The calculations in Python should use reduced precision as well. I looked into *decimal* module, with no success so far.

```
with open(‘datafile’,newline='') as DAQfile:
    reader=csv.reader(DAQfile,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
       … calculate stuff…

with open('results.csv','w',newline='') as myfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(myfile)
    …write stuff…
```

Adding some details, based on the comments so far:
The program calculates the peak of the moving average of the 'instantaneous power'. The data in the csv file can be described like this, where 'col' means column, V means voltage and I means current: col1=time, col2=V1, col3=I1, col4=V2, col5=I2 and so on until col11=V10, col12=I10. So each row represents a data sample taken by the DAQ.
The instantaneous power is Pi=V1*I1+V2*I2+...+V11*I11
To calculate moving average over 10000 rows at a time, I built a buffer (initialized with Buffer=[0]*10000). This buffer will store the Pi's for 10000 consecutive rows and will be updated every time when csv.reader moves to the next row. The buffer works exactly like a shift register.
This way the memory usage is insignificant (verified). In summary, the calculations are multiplications, additions, min(a,b) function (to detect the peak of the moving average) and del/append for refreshing the buffer. The moving average itself is iterative too, something like newavg=oldavg+(newlast-oldfirst)/bufsize.
My thinking is that it does not make any sense to let Python work with all those decimals when I know that most of the trailing figures are garbage.
 Forgot to mention that the size of the csv file coming from the DAQ is just under 1Gb.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into the nature of computations, not the precision. Many numeric operations can be substantially sped up by using NumPy.

Comment: I don't think so and even if you could I highly suspect that it would significantly improve the performance as `float`s are already very efficient. Are you sure the precision is the bottleneck? Try converting all the numbers to `int`s and do a benchmark first. If that doesn't help, reducing the precision can't either.

Comment: If it's a professional engagement, it's bad. Two things would be better for such large calculations. The first thing is binary data (CSV is stupid with so many numbers). The second thing is to increase the computing power by leaving Python Interpréter, so write a code for calculations in C or Assembler (unfortunately Assembler has a non-transferable machine code after compiling it)...

Comment: ...thus, calculations will only depend on the processor's CPU performance - usually on a regular PC, the whole calculation will take only a few seconds. If you have a server or a computer center like NASA, then Python will also be enough, because the calculation will end in a few microseconds :-D. I'm sorry for such complicated things as Python does not even use mathematical modules.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're doing with the data. If they are matrix operations then changing the algorithm could improve your time substantially.

Comment: Assuming your values are of type `float`, those values are in the native format for the floating-point unit in your processor, so switching to something like 7-digit-precision decimals will make things a whole lot _slower_, not faster. (Unless you're actually using 16-digit `decimal.Decimal` values—in which case switching to `float` will speed things up a whole lot more than 7-digit `Decimal`s.)

Comment: If you can't change your algorithm, usually the key is to (a) speed up the inner loop by using a numpy array, using numba.jit, running the script in PyPy instead of CPython, rewriting that inner loop in Cython (or C/C++/Rust/whatever), etc., and/or (b) parallelize the outer loop by using multiprocessing/concurrent.futures (or, sometimes, (c) using numba+CUDA to speed things up and parallelize them even more by pushing them to the GPU).

Comment: Measure first where time is spent, as [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/169494). (Without having measured it, I guess it's CVS parsing and writing.) Also, don't just think about micro-optimizations, but also parallelization on all levels: Vectorization, multi-threading, multi-processing. NumPy, PySpark etc. can help you do these.

Comment: One other thing that might be an issue is memory allocation. It looks like you're reading a file, parsing each row, and storing the results in some giant structure, then writing that structure out to a new file. If you can write the file iteratively as you go along, storing a lot less data, that can make a huge difference. (It also pipelines your I/O and CPU work a lot better, which can itself give you a small speedup.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way - use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). First, there are tons of vector/vector operations, which could be performed with one command

```
a = b + c
```

will efficiently sum two vector.

Second, which is the answer to your question, you could specify 4bytes float type, greatly reducing memory reqs and increasing speed.

You should read your file directly using

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
data = genfromtxt('datafile.csv', dtype=numpy.float32, delimiter=',')
...
```

`data` would made up from standard 32bits floats, circa 7digits precision.

CSV file could be read by parts/bunches

```
numpy.genfromtxt(fname, dtype=<class 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None,
skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None, missing_values=None, filling_values=None,
usecols=None, names=None, excludelist=None, deletechars=None, replace_space='_',
autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt='f%i',
unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True, max_rows=None,
encoding='bytes')
```

here is full list of parameters. If `max_rows` is set to, say, 10, only 10 rows will be read. Default is to read whole file. You could read anything in the middle of the files by skipping some initial records, via `skip_header` option.

Comment: This is interesting, but wouldn't this load the entire csv file at a time? I am talking almost 1Gb. I was using csv.reader because it is processing row by row, with minimum memory usage.

Comment: @NP1 PLease, check update. And, frankly, if you're looking into any kind of numeric (DAQ) processing, NumPy is pretty much a must

Comment: I'll think about this. I am afraid that reading in chunks will break the continuity of the moving average and may require more gymnastics than I was hoping... By the way, I am using NumPy in this code, but maybe not the exact way you are suggesting.

Comment: @NP1 Huh?!? What reading has to do with continuity of the moving average? You read into intermediate buffer some N records and start processing moving average. As soon as you at the end of the buffer you'll get IndexError exception, you catch it and refill the buffer by reading another part of CSV. Should be two absolutely separate mechanisms. And using exception  in Python for flow control is perfectly normal. Frankly, 1Gb of text CSV file should be pretty compact as NumPy float32 ndarray - I would say around 300M or so.

Answer (score -1):

Use DyZ's comment. if there is a way to speed up the calculations, (i.e. using << or >> for multiplications or divisions respectiveley if the second operand or the dividend is a power of 2, you should take it.
example:

```
>>> 22 * 16
352
>>> 22 << 4
352
```

in that scenario, I did the exact same operation with marginal decrease in time. However, if that will equate to 100 trillion calculations, the difference is much more notable.